# Can't access/set values of a null struct

Tags: c++, struct, null

I'm making a binary tree template class, and while this particular runtime error has never occurred initializing BST with ints, I haven't gotten around it initializing BST with strings. The error occurs on the marked line.

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include "BSTInterface.h"

template <typename T>
class BST : public BSTInterface<T>
{
public:
    BST()
    {
        root = new Node;
        root = NULL;
    }
    bool addNode(const T& newVal, Node *start)
    {
        start->data = newVal; // ERROR HERE
        return true;
    }
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
    };
    Node *root;
};
#endif
```

I've tried to set each of the values of root to null instead, but I get this build error:

```
BST.h(18): error C2593: 'operator =' is 
ambiguous
```

Line 18 is where I set start->data to null. Setting start->left and start->right to null don't give build errors.

I have to be able to set these to null rather than some arbitrary value in order for other code (that I'm not allowed to modify) to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Side effects of overminimalizing included.

```
#include "BST.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    BST<std::string> myBST;
    myBST.addNode("e");
}
```

Additional function in BST, the one actually being called from main:

```
bool addNode(const T& newVal)
{
    return addNode(newVal, root);
}
```

Edit 2: Code for BSTInterface

```
//**** YOU MAY NOT MODIFY THIS DOCUMENT ****/
#ifndef BST_INTERFACE_H
#define BST_INTERFACE_H
#include <string>

/** A binary tree node with data, left and right child pointers */
template<typename T>
class BSTInterface
{
public:
    BSTInterface(void) {}
    virtual ~BSTInterface(void) {}

    /** Return true if node added to BST, else false */
    virtual bool addNode(const T&) = 0;

    /** Return true if node removed from BST, else false */
    virtual bool removeNode(const T&) = 0;

    /** Return true if BST cleared of all nodes, else false */
    virtual bool clearTree() = 0;

    /** Return a level order traversal of a BST as a string */
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};
#endif  // BST_INTERFACE_H
```

Comment: You need a complete example. You have not shown how you're trying to use your code.

Comment: Talk with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) about `root = new Node;
        root = NULL;`

Comment: If I don't include both of those lines in, or at least set root to null in some way, the non-modifiable code (print function) won't work properly. Not experienced to be able to work around that.

Comment: Post edited to show the example I'm using.

Comment: The error message you get isn't what I'd expect. Do me  favour and forward declare `Node` up at the top of `class BST`. `class BST : public BSTInterface<T>
{ struct Node;
public:`

Comment: Don't ever introduce bugs (the null assignment to root) just to make code magically "work".

Comment: Done in the space you specified, got the same error.

Comment: @TroubledProgrammer You allocate a new `Node`, store a pointer to it in `root`, and then immediately store `NULL` in `root` losing the pointer to the new `Node` you just allocated. That's a pointless memory leak. What was the purpose of allocating a new node?

Comment: @David Schwartz Stupidity. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to try to reproduce the error:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
class BSTInterface
{
public:
    BSTInterface(void) {}
    virtual ~BSTInterface(void) {}

    /** Return true if node added to BST, else false */
    virtual bool addNode(const T&) = 0;

    /** Return true if node removed from BST, else false */
    virtual bool removeNode(const T&) = 0;

    /** Return true if BST cleared of all nodes, else false */
    virtual bool clearTree() = 0;

    /** Return a level order traversal of a BST as a string */
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class BST : public BSTInterface<T>
{
   private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
    };
    Node *root;
   public:
    BST()
    {
        root = new Node;
    }
    bool addNode(const T& newVal, Node *start)
    {
        start->data = newVal; // ERROR HERE
        return true;
    }
    bool removeNode(const T&) override {
        throw std::runtime_error("Not implemented yet"); 
    }
    bool clearTree() override {
        throw std::runtime_error("Not implemented yet"); 
    }
    std::string toString() const override {
        throw std::runtime_error("Not implemented yet"); 
    }

    bool addNode(const T& val) override {
        return addNode(val, root); 
    }

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    BST<std::string> myBST;
    myBST.addNode("e");
}
```

And I couldn't reproduce the error (it compiled fine). Could you provide the full code?

Comment: Only the addNode(const T& newVal) is inherited (part of the code I'm not allowed to modify) the second addNode function I wrote. Node is never mentioned in BSTInterface, only stubs for addNode, the constructor & destructor and a few other irrelevant functions.

Comment: Edited to have that.

Comment: Could you provide the full code that's giving the error? There wasn't enough to reproduce the error, and when I filled in the gaps in the code, it compiled fine (see above)

Comment: What David Schwartz pointed out in the comments is that I was trying to access the new Node via root after resetting root to null. I stopped trying to do that and that fixed it.